# Prosemirror scheme not detecting html styled element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, prose-mirror

I have the following HTML Content that i am converting to a prosemirror Document as follows

```
<div><p>Test<br>mcol<span style="color:#4472C4">oredtext</span></p><p><b><span style="color:#4472C4">test</span></b></p><ul style="margin-top:0in" type="disc"><li style="margin-left:0in;mso-list:l1 level1 lfo1">1</li><li style="margin-left:0in;mso-list:l1 level1 lfo1">2</li><li style="margin-left:0in;mso-list:l1 level1 lfo1">3</li></ul><ol style="margin-top:0in" start="1" type="1"><li style="margin-left:0in;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo2">101</li><li style="margin-left:0in;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo2">102</li><li style="margin-left:0in;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo2">103</li></ol><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:322.5pt;border-collapse:collapse"><tbody><tr><td style="width:64.5pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in"><p><a href="https://example.com/" target="_blank" title="https://example.com/"><span style="font-size:9.0pt;font-family:Roboto;color:#000068;text-decoration:none"><img border="0" style="width:1.0in;height:1.0in" src="cid:image001.jpg@01D8A66B.39C84F90" alt="signature_1667620787"></span></a></p></td><td style="width:33.0pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in"><p style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:9.0pt;font-family:Roboto;color:#343434"><img border="0" style="width:.1354in;height:1.0416in" src="cid:image002.png@01D8A66B.39C84F90" alt="Logo"></span></p></td><td style="width:225.0pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in"><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse"><tbody><tr><td style="padding:0in 0in 3.75pt 0in"><p><b><span style="font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:#2E2C2C">Bassem Alameddine</span></b></p></td></tr><tr><td style="padding:0in 0in 3.75pt 0in"><p style="background:white"><b><span style="font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:#2E2C2C">Full Stake Developer and Team Leader</span></b></p></td></tr><tr><td style="padding:0in 0in .75pt 0in"></td></tr><tr><td style="padding:0in 0in .75pt 0in"><p><b><span style="font-size:9.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:#2E2C2C">E:&nbsp;</span></b><a href="mailto:bassem.alameddine@example.com"><span style="color:#00B0F0">bassem.alameddine</span><span style="font-size:9.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:#00B0F0">@example.com</span></a><span style="font-size:9.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:#2E2C2C">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span><a href="http://example.com/" target="_blank" title="http://example.com/"><span style="font-size:9.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:#2DABE8">example.com</span></a></p></td></tr><tr><td style="padding:7.5pt 0in 0in 0in"><p style="margin-bottom:12.0pt"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/example/" target="_blank" title="https://www.facebook.com/example/"><span style="font-family:Roboto;color:#265E8A;text-decoration:none"><img border="0" style="width:.2083in;height:.2083in" src="cid:image003.png@01D8A66B.39C84F90" alt="Facebook icon"></span></a><span style="font-family:Roboto">&nbsp;</span><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/example" target="_blank" title="https://www.linkedin.com/company/example"><span style="font-family:Roboto;color:#265E8A;text-decoration:none"><img border="0" style="width:.2083in;height:.2083in" src="cid:image004.png@01D8A66B.39C84F90" alt="LinkedIn icon"></span></a><span style="font-family:Roboto">&nbsp;</span><a href="https://twitter.com/examplesal" target="_blank" title="https://twitter.com/examplesal"><span style="font-family:Roboto;color:#265E8A;text-decoration:none"><img border="0" style="width:.2083in;height:.2083in" src="cid:image005.png@01D8A66B.39C84F90" alt="Twitter icon"></span></a><span style="font-family:Roboto">&nbsp;</span><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCmty_DpLAqoaIiz1GZyfdrw" target="_blank" title="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCmty_DpLAqoaIiz1GZyfdrw"><span style="font-family:Roboto;color:#265E8A;text-decoration:none"><img border="0" style="width:.2083in;height:.2083in" src="cid:image006.png@01D8A66B.39C84F90" alt="Youtube icon"></span></a><span style="font-family:Roboto">&nbsp;</span></p></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
```

The output document is not detecting the `mcoloredtext` as a separated paragraph node, instead it is returned as 1 paragraph how can I fix this?

[image]

this is the html output

[image]

my code is the following:

```
   import { DOMParser as DP } from "prosemirror-model";
   import { defaultSchema } from '@atlaskit/adf-schema/schema-default';
  const pmNode = DP.fromSchema(defaultSchema).parse(htmlbody);
```